# In dm-cache, does the metadata volume need to be redundant?

Tags: linux, lvm, ssd, storage, bcache

I currently have a pool of hard drive storage in LVM, arranged such that each physical volume is an mdraid mirror device, so that I have full redundancy. Now, I'd like to add a SSD cache to this pool using dm-cache, but I only need write-through caching (writes aren't much of a concern), and because of that I'd like to not have to use mirrored SSDs.

However, I'm having trouble finding information on how the dm-cache metadata volume should be treated, namely in the following regards:

- Does it need to be mirrored despite the actual cache not being mirrored?
- If it needs to be mirrored, can it be put on the already mirrored hard drive PVs instead of the SSD, or is performance on the metadata volume important?
- Given that the cache is always clean in write-through mode, what happens if the meta-data volume is lost? How easy is it to recover the VG?

I'm aware that bcache doesn't have this problem at all, but I'd have to reinitialize all my PVs to use bcache instead, which is why I'd prefer to use dm-cache.